Is using the word "each" in the claims considered patent profanity?
for example:
"storing a plurality of profiles belonging to a plurality of users in at least one database, each profile having at least one parameter;"
I remember that the word "each" is on the list of patent profanity.
Is it also the case when the word "each" is used in the claims, as opposed to the specifications?
